# Seeking the derivation of the Fourier Sine Transform of $x^{2\nu}(x^2+a^2)^{-\mu-1}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, special-functions

In [this answer on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2412366/64809) the Fourier Sine Transform of $x^{2\nu}(x^2+a^2)^{-\mu-1}$ is given in terms of the generalized hypergeometric function:
$$\frac{1}{2}a^{2\nu-2\mu}\frac{\Gamma(1+\nu)\Gamma(\mu-\nu)}{\Gamma(\mu+1)}y \:_1\text{F}_2(\nu+1;\nu+1-\mu,3/2;a^2y^2/4)\:+\:4^{\nu-\mu-1}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\nu-\mu)}{\Gamma(\mu-\nu+3/2)}y^{2\mu-2\nu+1}\:_1\text{F}_2(\mu+1;\mu-\nu+3/2,\mu-\nu+1;a^2y^2/4).
$$
In particular, the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(x)}{1+x^2} dx$ is expressed in terms of the error functions:
$$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\:e}\left(-e^2\text{erfc}(1)+\text{erf}(1) +1\right).$$

However, no derivation is provided there. I am seeking a derivation of the above expressions.

Comment: Derive differential equation satisfied by this Fourier transform as a function of $ay$, and show that this is equation for generalized hypergeomeric function https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8. Then write down linear combination of independent solutions and find coefficients considering series expansion around $ay=0$.

Comment: @Nemo: It seems easier said than done. The expression is a sum of two terms each of which is a product of some special functions and $\:_1\text{F}_2$. The two F's belong to distinct rather than a single generalized hypergeometric ODE's. You need to separate the terms first, which itself is a task unsolved.

Comment: compare the two linearly independent solutions of Gauss' hypergeometric equation https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.10.E2 . They seemingly belong to different hypergeometric ODE's.

Comment: There is also another method by using [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) to calculate Mellin transform of $f(x)=\frac{\sin xy}{(x^2+1)^{\mu+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(n)(-x)^n$. So I just told you 2 different methods how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Nemo: Thank you. The Ramanujan's master theorem method looks promising. I will try that. But I am still at a loss with your suggestion regarding Gauss' hypergeometric equation. Are you suggesting that each of the integrals in the question actually does satisfy one ODE or just that the right-hand side expression does not preclude the left-hand side from satisfying one single ODE?

Comment: I didn't check it but I suspect that both functions satisfy the same ODE despite their different appearances.

Comment: @Nemo: Would you take a look at my answer below? Does this $\xi$ function give you any idea to proceed and make connection with the error function?

Answer (score 1):

We follow Nemo's suggestion in the comment and derive an expression for $$f(x):=\frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda(k) x^k$$
to use Ramanujan's master theorem. We can do this in 2 ways.

1) Direct expansion:
$$f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m\frac{x^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^n = \sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^px^{2p+1}\sum_{m=0}^p\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}$$
Apparently, we need a meromorphic function $\xi(x)$ satisfying the functional equation
$$\xi(z+1)=\xi(z)+\frac1{\Gamma\big(2(z+1)\big)}$$
for which the inner summation as a function of $p$ would be a discrete case. What is this $\xi(z)$?

2)

$f(x)$ satisfies the following ODE
$$(1+x^2)\,f''+4x\,f'-(3+x^2)\,f=0,\;\;f(0)=0,\; f'(0)=1.$$
The Frobenius method gives
\begin{align}
\phi(2k)&=0 \\
\phi(1)&=1 \\
\phi(3)=-\phi(1)&= -1 \\
\phi(k+2)+(k^2+3k-3)\phi(k)-k(k-1)\phi(k-2) &= 0
\end{align}

(to be continued)

Comment: The part marked 2) is not needed. $\xi$ can be written as a hypergeometric function with parameters dependent on $z$, so that when $z=-p$ it reduces to a finite sum.

Comment: By the way the wikipedia article is not complete. There is formula 11.19.4 from Hardy's book "Ramanujan, Twelve lectures suggested by his life and work" that will be more useful.